# Adding HSTS header to website using .htaccess file

Tags: html, .htaccess

To improve website security, I want to add a HSTS preload header using the .htaccess file and have tried various solutions from other websites.

Below is the current rewrite code we use within the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

So far I have removed the previous code and added the below but didn't get any luck when testing.

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
```

Comment: How is your SSL currently managed?

Comment: How are you testing this? And what do you mean by "didn't get any luck when testing"? Is the header not set? An error? You should implement HSTS on a short time scale before attempting to implement "preload", as stated on the preload list website. "So far I have removed the previous code" - You still need to implement the redirects, just not in the order stated.

Comment: Tested by removing the previous rewrite engine code, replacing it with the Header set code and then uploading the .htaccess file before testing it on https://hstspreload.org/

Comment: SSL currently managed through hosting provider

Comment: "SSL currently managed through hosting provider" - So, are you behind a front-end proxy that manages the clients HTTPS connection? The use of `X-Forwarded-Proto` suggests you are, but the use of the `HTTPS` server var suggests you are not - both are not required (was this HTTP to HTTPS redirect rule just copy/pasted from elsewhere?). This matters because this header needs to be set conditionally based on whether HTTPS is active or not.

Comment: You can (and should) test this yourself by analyzing the HTTP response from the server for various requests - this is the only reasonable way to actually "debug" this, since there are several parts to this.

Comment: I believe the HTTP to HTTPS redirect rule was copied from somewhere else by the previous 'guy'. During an SEO audit, the lack of HSTS header was flagged and needed adding. I am unsure as to how to implement the HSTS header with the current code or whether the previous rewrite code needs to be removed altogether. Any help would be appreciated and I understand I'm communicating the issue poorly